# How come my JavaScript isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a login page for school. I have written the page, but the JavaScript does not seem to work with the form. I have checked over both the form and the JavaScript multiple times, but I see no mistake. Can anyone help me?

```js
function processInfo() {
  var theusername;
  var thepassword;

  theusername = document.myForm.username.value;
  thepassword = document.myForm.password.value;

  if (document.myForm.username.value = "") {
    alert("Please enter in the username.")
    return false;
  } else if (document.myForm.password = "") {
    alert("Please enter in the password.")
    return false;
  } else if (document.myForm.username.value != "andrew123") {
    document.myForm.txtOutput.value = "Incorrect username or password."
  } else if (thepassword != "abc") {
    document.myForm.txtOutput.value = "Incorrect username or password."
  } else if (theusername == "andrew123"
    thepassword == "abc") {
    document.myForm.txtOutput.value = "Correct! You have successfully logged in."
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <b>User Name:</b>
  <input type="text" name="username" size="36" maxlength="100">

  <b>Password:</b>
  <input type="text" name="password" size="36" maxlength="100">

  <p>
    <input type=button value="VERIFY INFORMATION" onClick=processInfo()>
  </p>
  <textarea name="txtOutput" rows=1 cols=4 0></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Missing '&&'  else if(theusername =="andrew123" && thepassword=="abc"){

Comment: What problem do you experience?  `does not seem to work` is not descriptive.

Comment: Are you getting errors in the Javascript console? Before you come here, that should always be the first place you check.

Comment: You need to compare with `==` or `===`, your first two if block conditions are incorrect. So is your last, but @Nasir already pointed out the issue with that.

Comment: I fixed a DOM error in your code while updating it to use the site fiddle. Your paragraph node was unclosed.

Comment: You also need to use `onclick="return processInfo()"` so that the return value of the function will be used.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 4):

`=` is an *assignment*, you keep using it when you are trying to perform a comparison (which would use `==` or `===`).

---

Sometimes you try to compare the form control with a string instead of getting its `.value`.

---

You forgot to put a boolean AND between the two conditions you have `theusername == "andrew123"
    thepassword == "abc"`

---

You should learn to use [the console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) in your browser as most of these problems would be highlighted in it or could be with the addition of a little logging.